# Update table SQL query help

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a database student(attribute - studentid). studentid is a varchar. Now I want to add 'P' at the end of all studentids.

12 -> 12P
234 -> 234P

What will be the sql query for this?

Comment: Do you want to add the P to the values in the database, or when you return the values?  If you are wanting to update the values in the studentid column, have you updated it to be a string instead of an int type?

Comment: Please post the current table definition (i.e. the `CREATE TABLE` statement), and the brand of RDBMS you use.  Any answer will depend on this information.

Comment: studentid is a varchar...my bad..I am using SQL server 2005..I want to add P to the values in the database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE mytable SET student_id=CONCAT(student_id,'P');//mysql
```

Answer (score 4):

```
UPDATE mytable
SET student_id = student_id + 'P'   --assumes already varchar 
WHERE RIGHT(student_id, 1) <> 'P'   --to stop having PP at end...
```

Comment: using Where condition to stop 'PP' is really smart. This is somthing which avoid future unwanted errors.

Answer (score 2):

This is for SQL Server:

```
select cast(Studentid as varchar) +'P' from student
```

Answer (score 2):

```
update @t
set studentid = studentid + 'P'
```